# Helm secrets plugin unable to decrypt secrets.yaml encrypted before with GPG key

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, gnupg, kubernetes-secrets

I have got a problem with decryption of my secrets.yaml file. The process freez like on pic. below:
[helm secrets dec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs9lQ.png)

Based on the example from official documentation: https://github.com/futuresimple/helm-secrets

1) I have my gpg key fingerprint added in the .sops.yaml

2) I make custom secrets.yaml file to encrypt:

```
replicaCount:
image:
    repository: git/repo    
    tag:   v1
    pullPolicy: always
service:
    type: nodeport
    port:   3456
    targetPort: 4665
ingress:
    enabled: true
```

Then I successfully encrypted this file with my key:
[helm secrets enc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZCTj.png)

File is properly encrypted but unfortunetly I am not able to decrypt it back.
The command is suspended indefinitely as on the [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhVfj.png)

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure that helps me to solve this problem, but I made new GPG key WITHOUT PASS PHRASE. Propably SOPS was able to encrypt file, but can't obtain it to decryption. Hope it helps someone !